# Automatically running ANALYZE on PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

What's the easiest way to automatically run `ANALYZE <table>;` on a PostgreSQL 12 server, aside from a cronjob?

I have an application where millions of rows are routinely inserted each week, and after a month or so, query times become very slow because statistics are out of date for the primary tables being modified. Running `ANALYZE <table>;` for the tables takes a couple minutes and immediately fixes the performance issues, but I reason there has to be a setting I can make so this can be done automatically by the PG server itself instead of manually?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have autovacuum disabled, which if it were enabled would analyze all of your tables periodically to update their statistics for the query planner.

The simplest solution is to re-enable autovacuum. Check your postgresql.conf file for the autovacuum setting.

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL has a built-in autovavuum that should be enabled and configured to match your needs. Typically you adjust *autovacuum_vacuum_threshold * and *autovacuum_analyze_threshold* to kick off desired behavior based on the number of changed tuples.

See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/routine-vacuuming.html#AUTOVACUUM